# Array isn't fetching all data because of if statement

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, while-loop

I believe my code isn't fully working because I have while loops inside a if statement, and is only allowing the loop to run once. The code is allowing an admin to view an order and access all of the information about that order. However with the code like it is, it only views one product, even if the order contains 2 or more. Below is my php code block

```
if (isset($_GET['orderid'])){
$targetID = $_GET['orderid'];
//query to find the item
$products_ordered = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `transactions` WHERE `order_id` ='$targetID' LIMIT 1");
$orderCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);

while ($transactions = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    //creating variables from the information
    $order_id = $transactions["order_id"];
    $mem_id = $transactions["mem_id"];
    $OrderDate = $transactions["OrderDate"];
    $ship_phone = $transactions["ship_phone"];
    $ship_address = $transactions["ship_address"];
    $ship_city = $transactions["ship_city"];
    $ship_county = $transactions["ship_county"];
    $ship_postcode = $transactions["ship_postcode"];
    $ship_country = $transactions["ship_country"];

    $order_details = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `transactionDetails` WHERE `order_id` = $order_id") or die(mysql_error());
    $orderDetailsCount = mysql_num_rows($order_details);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($order_details)) {
        //creating variables from the information
        $order_details_id = $row["Order_details_ID"];
        $order_product_id = $row["Product_ID"];
        $order_product_price = $row["Price"];
        $order_product_quantity = $row["Quantity"];

        $member_details = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `mem_id` = $mem_id") or die(mysql_error());
        $memberDetailsCount = mysql_num_rows($member_details);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($member_details)) {
            //creating variables from the information
            $order_mem_fname = $row["mem_first_name"];
            $order_mem_lname = $row["mem_last_name"];

            $product_details = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `id` = $order_product_id") or die(mysql_error());
            while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($product_details)) {
            //creating variables from the information
            $product_name = $row1["product_name"];

            $products_ordered = "<tr>
            <td width=\"20%\">Product Name</td>
            <td width=\"80%\"><label> $product_name
            </label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width=\"20%\">Quantity</td>
            <td width=\"80%\"><label> $order_product_quantity
            </label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width=\"20%\">Price per Item</td>
            <td width=\"80%\"><label> $order_product_price
            </label></td>
            </tr>";
                }
        }
    }
}

if ($orderCount == 0) {
echo "Sorry, order doesn't exist";
exit();
}
}
```

And this is my table which contains the data

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%">Order ID:</td>
                <td width="80%"><label><?php echo $order_id; ?> </label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%">Order Date</td>
                <td width="80%"><label><?php echo $OrderDate; ?> </label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%">First Name</td>
                <td width="80%"><label><?php echo $order_mem_fname; ?> </label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%">Last Name</td>
                <td width="80%"><label><?php echo $order_mem_lname; ?> </label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%">Contact Number</td>
                <td width="80%"><label><?php echo $ship_phone; ?> </label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%">Address</td>
                <td width="80%"><label><?php echo $ship_address; ?> </label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%">City</td>
                <td width="80%"><label><?php echo $ship_city; ?> </label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%">County</td>
                <td width="80%"><label><?php echo $ship_county; ?> </label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%">Post Code</td>
                <td width="80%"><label><?php echo $ship_postcode; ?> </label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%">Country</td>
                <td width="80%"><label><?php echo $ship_country; ?> </label></td>
            </tr>
            <?php echo $products_ordered;?>
        </table>
```

Comment: Remove 'LIMIT 1' From your SQL. It is only return the first record

Comment: The outer while loop doesn't need to be there, or you should change the line `$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE order_id ='$targetID' LIMIT 1");` as you limit the result set to one return.

Comment: I removed the LIMIT 1 however it made no difference. All that was doing was only allowing one order_id which is correct as 1 order_id can have many product_id's

Comment: Have you tried to echo your $orderDetailsCount variable? What does it say?

Comment: @Yellowledbet if I echo out $order_product_id it shows my order_ID's, however it only fetches information for one

Comment: Check out my response below; your output is not concatenated to the previous output which means it will only show one product every single time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You save the output in a variable and the next time it goes through the code it will override the original value.

Instead of

```
$products_ordered = "<tr>
```

You should do that

```
$products_ordered .= "<tr> // notice the dot to concatenate the original html with the new html
```

If your first query returns 2 results and you expect 2 products that means each while loop within the main loop must loop at least once.

Print each count values and make sure the first one shows `2` and the other ones show `1`. If it doesn't always show `1` it means your database is missing data.

You can also avoid this issue by using [SQL JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html). That way, you can directly test the final output with a SQL client or phpmyadmin.

Also, your code is open to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection) because you are using `mysql_*` functions and the query parameters are not [sanitized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_sanitization#Preventing_code_injection). Instead you should use [MySQLi](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). As a temporary solution, you could typecast `$_GET['orderid']` to an integer or check if `$_GET['orderid']` is an integer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a complicated way to get your data, which could be done with some JOINs and fewer (perhaps one) queries.

Your problem is that you use $row at two levels : with $order_details and with $member_details. As you have only one member per order, there is nothing more to retrieve for the second order line.